# How to make ViewModel display network data on first run

Tags: java, android, android-volley, android-mvvm

I am just getting into Android Architecture and have encountered an issue after following [this tutorial by mitch](https://github.com/mitchtabian/MVVMExample1):
ViewModel doesn't show any data **from the internet- I'm using volley- on first run**.
The UI remains blank and only shows data on the views only onChange. i.e A screen rotation/refresh

If I manually set this data, it shows them on first run as required
i.e **dataSet.add(new DecodeHouseDetails(1,1,1,"H2345","treutue.jpg","House 1","4345423232312","3224342434232") ); //Add data to the mutatable list**

But once I include the network data, it misbehaves.

I have tried checking if my repository could be returning a null list on first run but the toast attached inside the repository shows that the data was well received, only that I dont understand why it wont display until either a change in screen rotation or a refresh

**My Repository**

```
public class GetHouseDetailsRepository {
    private Context mContext;
    private static final String URL_initializeDashboard= CustomFunctions.root_house_admin_url+"initialize_dashboard";
    CustomFunctions func= new CustomFunctions();

    private static GetHouseDetailsRepository instance;
    private ArrayList<DecodeHouseDetails> dataSet= new ArrayList<>();
    private JSONObject jsonObject;

    public static GetHouseDetailsRepository getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new GetHouseDetailsRepository();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    //Make a mutable list of the data that we will be getting from the database
    public MutableLiveData<List<DecodeHouseDetails>> getHouseDetails(Context mContext){
        this.mContext=mContext;
        getDatabaseHouseDetails();

        MutableLiveData<List<DecodeHouseDetails>> myData= new MutableLiveData<>();
        if(dataSet ==null){
            getDatabaseHouseDetails();
        }
        myData.setValue(dataSet);
        return myData;
    }

    //Method to actually get the data from the database
    public void getDatabaseHouseDetails(){
        //dataSet.add(new DecodeHouseDetails(1,1,1,"H2345","treutue.jpg","Keja Mkononi","1","A nice house","Water,electrivit","Other amenities","5","1","Embu","1","1","1","1","4345423232312","3224342434232") ); //Add data to the mutatable list
        jsonObject= new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("me",""+func.getSharedUserID(mContext) );//Logged in user
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSONObject Here", e.toString());
        }
        VolleyNetworkRequestInterfaceSingleton.getResponse(mContext,Request.Method.GET, URL_initializeDashboard, jsonObject,new VolleyNetworkRequestInterfaceSingleton.VolleyCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccessResponse(String response) {
                if(response!=null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                        //Successfully fetched
                        String sarray = json.getString("house_details");
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, sarray, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(sarray);

                        //Clear list to refresh list in every selection
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject json_list = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            DecodeHouseDetails houses_array = new DecodeHouseDetails(
                                    json_list.getInt("active_identifier"),
                                    json_list.getInt("house_id"),
                                    json_list.getInt("house_status"),
                                    json_list.getString("house_number"),
                                    json_list.getString("house_cover"),
                                    json_list.getString("house_name"),
                                    json_list.getString("longitude"),
                                    json_list.getString("latitude")
                            );
                            dataSet.add(houses_array);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**My ViewModel**

```
public class GetHouseDetailsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    //The data we fetch from asynchronously
    private MutableLiveData<List<DecodeHouseDetails>> mHouseDetailsList;
    private GetHouseDetailsRepository mHouseDetailsRepository;

    public GetHouseDetailsViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    public void init(){
        if(mHouseDetailsList != null){
            mHouseDetailsList= new MutableLiveData<>();
        }
        mHouseDetailsRepository = GetHouseDetailsRepository.getInstance(); //Initialize the repository
        mHouseDetailsList = mHouseDetailsRepository.getHouseDetails(this.getApplication());
    }

    public LiveData<List<DecodeHouseDetails>> getHouseInfo() {
        if(mHouseDetailsList == null){
            mHouseDetailsList = new MutableLiveData<>();
        }
        return mHouseDetailsList;
    }
}
```

**My View - Fragment**

```
public class AdmManageHouses extends Fragment {
    private ProgressBar progressloader,progressloader_large;
    SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
    private TextView house_number_text,house_title_text,house_name_text;
    private GetHouseDetailsViewModel mHouseDetailsViewModel;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_manage_houses, container, false);
        mHouseDetailsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(GetHouseDetailsViewModel.class);

        //Innitialize objects
        house_title_text= rootView.findViewById(R.id.house_title);
        house_number_text= rootView.findViewById(R.id.house_number);
        house_name_text= rootView.findViewById(R.id.house_name);

        //Initialize the view model
        mHouseDetailsViewModel.init();
        mHouseDetailsViewModel.getHouseInfo().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<DecodeHouseDetails>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<DecodeHouseDetails> decodeHouseDetails) {
                for(int i=0; i<decodeHouseDetails.size(); i++) {
                    house_number_text.setText(String.valueOf(decodeHouseDetails.get(i).getHouse_number()));
                    house_title_text.setText(decodeHouseDetails.get(i).getHouse_name());
                    house_name_text.setText(decodeHouseDetails.get(i).getHouse_name());
                }
            }
        });

        //Refresh on swipe
       refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                initializeDashboard();
                refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        initializeDashboard();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void initializeDashboard() {
        for(int i=0; i<mHouseDetailsViewModel.getHouseInfo().getValue().size(); i++) {

            house_number_text.setText(String.valueOf(mHouseDetailsViewModel.getHouseInfo().getValue().get(i).getHouse_number()));
            house_title_text.setText(mHouseDetailsViewModel.getHouseInfo().getValue().get(i).getHouse_name());
            house_name_text.setText(mHouseDetailsViewModel.getHouseInfo().getValue().get(i).getHouse_name());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After thorough checking of the viewmodel, I discovered that problem was in the repository and not the viewModel. I was not calling setValue() properly.
This made the first run - when the list is null - fail to populate the UI until onChange.
I made the following changes to the repository

i.e 
Declare myData variable

```
Private MutableLiveData<List<DecodeHouseDetails>> myData= new MutableLiveData<>();

//Make a mutable list of the data that we will be getting from the database
    public MutableLiveData<List<DecodeHouseDetails>> getHouseDetails(Context mContext){
        this.mContext=mContext;
        getDatabaseHouseDetails();

        return myData;
    }

    //Method to actually get the data from the database
    public void getDatabaseHouseDetails(){
        //dataSet.add(new DecodeHouseDetails(1,1,1,"H2345","treutue.jpg","Keja Mkononi","1","A nice house","Water,electrivit","Other amenities","5","1","Embu","1","1","1","1","4345423232312","3224342434232") ); //Add data to the mutatable list
        jsonObject= new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("me",""+func.getSharedUserID(mContext) );//Logged in user
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSONObject Here", e.toString());
        }
        VolleyNetworkRequestInterfaceSingleton.getResponse(mContext,Request.Method.GET, URL_initializeDashboard, jsonObject,new VolleyNetworkRequestInterfaceSingleton.VolleyCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccessResponse(String response) {
                if(response!=null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                        //Successfully fetched
                        String sarray = json.getString("house_details");
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, sarray, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(sarray);

                        //Clear list to refresh list in every selection
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject json_list = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            DecodeHouseDetails houses_array = new DecodeHouseDetails(
                                    json_list.getInt("active_identifier"),
                                    json_list.getInt("house_id"),
                                    json_list.getInt("house_status"),
                                    json_list.getString("house_number"),
                                    json_list.getString("house_cover"),
                                    json_list.getString("house_name"),
                                    json_list.getString("longitude"),
                                    json_list.getString("latitude")
                            );
                            dataSet.add(houses_array);
                        }

                        myData.setValue(dataSet);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```